# How many habitats can I fit on an island grid?

Tags: dragonvale

I'm planning to dedicate a couple islands to battery farms (all dragons, no decoration) so I'll have more space in the rest of my park. However this is proving non-trivial because:

- The island grid is a [very awkward, non-symmetrical shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re9zb.png)
- Habitats range in size from 2×2 to 8×8 (they're all squares though)
- Each island has to accommodate one 3×3 Entrance Portal somewhere as well

[image: Island grid small]

Just brute-forcing it, I can fit 13 large rainbow habitats (6×6) on one island, but I feel like if I did it optimally I could squeeze in at least one more.

So, for each habitat size, I'd like to know: How many habitats can I fit on a single island?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this has been unanswered for a while, but I got bored and I wanted to know the answer to this anyways, so I made a blog post on the subject over at this [link](https://createimaginewrite.wordpress.com/2015/10/09/how-many-of-each-size-habitat-fit-on-a-dragonvale-island/). Cheers!

Comment: Hello. Thanks for taking the time to answer a question. However, link-only answers (like this one) are frowned upon here, as they can't answer the questions themselves if the link goes down or is changed. To make this a better answer, please [edit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/239132/edit) it so it contains a brief summary of the main information in the link. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! I knew there had to be a way to get 14 Rainbows on one island.

Comment: and it happened.